# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] when a new page is added (AngularJS)

Tags: html, angularjs

Everything was OK until a new page (meaning page.js + page.html as files, then included in the lists of existing pages in order to be reachable in app.js and index.html) is added. We are not using any of the following anywhere and until this point everything worked fine, but now any new page goes to brake any other page showing the "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]" error.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js">     
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.min.js">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.min.js">
```

P.S. Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you added that is causing these problems?

Comment: I literally tried with empty page.js and page.html files in a folder with the same name (as every other page), that was working before when we were adding the first pages, but not even that doesn't work. Tried copying and renaming another folder and the files contained and included it in the index and app - same result. Also another quirk - as long as the new pages are not mentioned in those 2 files, they can still exists in their folders and the current site does not brake.

Answer (score 1):

Your error has nothing to do with the fact you added a new html file. The error in essence means that you are calling a module that is not being found. There is either a missing reference to the javascript file containing the module in index.html or you are missing a dependency like:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['missingModule']);
```